# Visual Studio Code - The window has crashed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just download and installed Visual Studio Code.

Windows x64 version 1.40.1

After I installed, I tryed opening it, but got the following error:

> The window has crashed
>
> We are sorry for the inconvenience! You can reopen the window to continue where you left off.

[image: Visual Studio Code error - the window has crashed]

I'm running on Windows 10 - 64 bits

What I tried, without success:

- reinstalling Visual Studio Code
- restarting my machine
- installing 32 bit version of VS Code
- installing Insiders edition of VS Code

Comment: Can you please , how your problem was solved? @Daniel

Comment: @prax I just uninstalled VS Code and then installed the most recent version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the problem was solved when I installed Visual Studio Code version 1.44.2.

Comment: Sir, I still have this problem. I'm on Win7 x64, the latest version of VScode `1.64.2`. I didn't face this issue on my previous windows (Win7 x64), I set up an `SSD` drive and installed a new Windows, now I have this problem. Even reinstalled VScode 3 times. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Install 32 bit version of vscode.
It will work on both 32 and 64bit. But in my experience the 32 bit version does not face more issues as compared to 64.

[What is the quantifiable benefit of 64 bit for Visual Studio Code over 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788213/what-is-the-quantifiable-benefit-of-64-bit-for-visual-studio-code-over-32-bit)

Comment: check base software version for nodejs and related required software/modules before installing it.